# Extracting elements from the start of a list in Haskell without the builtin function

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that extracts n number of elements from the start of a list in Haskell. I know it can be done using the built-in 'take' function and I have done it, which works. However, I can't seem to write a function without take.
This is my code.

```
takeElem' :: Int -> [t] -> [t]
takeElem' _ [] = []
takeElem' n (x:xs) = [x] ++ takeElem' (n-1) xs
```

This code complies fine but when I test it for example

```
takeElem' 3 "hello"
```

It returns "hello" instead of "hel"

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You haven’t used or matched on `n` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the last equation for `takeElem'` I suggest using list constructor `:` instead of creation of a singleton list `[x]` and using `++`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't add what should happen in the case when n is zero. I just added

```
takeElem' 0 list = []
```

it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 0 _ instead of _ [].
Because you are saying it is [] when you took everything of the list instead of [] when your n reaches 0.